# usage of it vs itself

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> One scary example is a 2016 Google thought experiment, euphemistically
> called ‘Project X’, that openly hypothesised behavioural data being
> “given a volition or purpose rather than simply acting as a historical
> reference,” that “reflect Google’s values as an organisation.” In
> effect, if Google decided as a company **it** wanted to address a societal
> problem like global warming, or, alternatively, endorse a political
> candidate that would give them a massive tax break, this suggested it
> could use data and automated processes to achieve that end.

I guess the bolded 'it' refers to Google, but then 'itself' seems to be more natural to me. Is it common to use it as reflexive use?

Comment: That is not a reflexive use of *it*.

Comment: If you add back the optional **relative pronoun** that is omitted here, I think you'll see this more clearly: _if Google decided as a company **that** it wanted to address... if Bob decided as a person **that** he wanted to address..._

Comment: Using "itself" here would change the meaning of the sentence. I think "it" is perfectly appropriate and is not a reflexive use in this case.